# how to change pitch of voice and create different sound effects in Flutter

Tags: flutter, audio

Guys I am trying to create a voice changer app and I am using flutter sounds package to access mic and record and play the audio but I want to create different sound effects for example when the button is clicked, two options shows up with which change the voice to male or female sounds.How should I do this?

I created the recording and playing voice features but I need different voice effects